# SHAREPOINT WORKFLOW: set field list thru email from worflow

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

May I ask if there's a way I could set a field (Status) thru email notification I received? Please see image below. ex. there's two link approved; rejected once I click approved it will automatically set field value of status to approved and vice versa. Thanks for the reply in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could create the url for each action as a variable. The url would point to the workflow start form. The user will need the click the link in the email first and then click the start button on the initiation form.